# Bug in Area 51 badge counting mechanism?

Tags: support, badges, area-51

There seems to be a bug in the Area 51 badge counting mechanism:

- On a [proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43029/amateur-radio), the top bar mentions a bronze badge count of six.
- However, on a [discussion page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10768/we-need-to-reach-out-now), an additional `Editor` badge is taken into account, totaling the number of bronze badges at seven.
- On both top bars, the reputation count is the same.

[image: proposal top bar]
[image: discussion top bar]

Answer (score 4):

`discuss` is the Area 51 Meta site.

Like all other Meta sites except Meta Stack Overflow, you share reputation between the main site and it's meta, but *not* badges. You earn badges on Meta sites independently.

The Area 51 software stack is really showing its age here; it is slated to be [updated](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/next-generation-of-area-51) for a while now, but documentation about this kind of detail is indeed lacking.

The new help center for the current software stack has this to say:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on *main site name* (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

See the [page about meta on Programmers help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) for example.

Comment: +1 I was wondering about that as well

Comment: @MartijnPieters That explains the logic behind it. However, from an Area 51 user perspective, **it really gives a defective impression.** This impression is strengthened by the fact that there unlike launched sites, there are almost **no visual clues** to distinguish between the main and meta sites.

Comment: I quite agree that Area 51 has many aspects that are severely broken. An overhaul was in the works over a year ago, I have no idea what the status of that overhaul is now.

Comment: The last [public post](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/is-a-new-area-51-site-under-development) discussing the update was in Jan.